# PySpark Broadcast Variable Join

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am performing a join, and I have my data across over 100 nodes. So I have a small list of key/value that I am joining with another key/value pair.

My list looks like such:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0], [10, 0], [11, 0], [16, 0], [18, 0], [19, 0], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0], [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [36, 0], [37, 0], [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [44, 0], [46, 0]]
```

I have broadcast variable:

```
numB = sc.broadcast(numValuesKV)
```

When I do my join:

```
numRDD = columnRDD.join(numB.value)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Answer (score 2):

you are broadcasting a list, which is absolutely fine.

what you need to do is

```
b=sc.broadcast(lst)
rdd.map(lambda t: t if t[0] in b.value)
```

here t[0] should look like [1,0] etc. But I hope you got the idea....

Answer (score 1):

can you try making numValuesKV a dictionary and see if it works.

Comment: +1 I had the same question.. my attempts to convert broadcast value into a dictionary resulted in TypeError: 'Broadcast' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

`rdd.join(other)` is mean to join two RDDs, therefore it expects `other` to be an RDD. To use the efficient 'small table broadcast' join trick, you need to do the join 'by hand'. In Scala, it would look like this:

```
rdd.mapPartitions{iter =>
    val valueMap = numB.value.toMap
    iter.map{case (k,v) => (k,(v,map(v))}
}
```

This applies the join using the broadcast value to each partition of the RDD in a distributed manner.

PySpark code should be pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try in python. So I have been using join as a very inefficent filter. What I am essentially doing is trying to keep only the key's in that list. Join's are expensive but I've been trying to play around with how to filter out the keys != that list with no success.

Comment: If the intention is to filter, instead of `iter.map` use `iter.filter(cond)` and you're done.